# How to reload Google Map in Bootstrap jQuery Tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gmaps.js to load 2 maps in Bootstrap tabs. What happens, is the first map loads fine, but when the second tab (hidden) is clicked, the map doesn't load properly. After extensive Googling, I realize that this has to do with the Google map needing to be resized upon the click of the tab, as Google maps don't play nicely with hidden tabs. However, after trying many things, I just can't get it to work. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PueE/

```
/**
  * Fort Collins Map
  */
$(document).ready(function () {
map = new GMaps({
  div: '#fort-collins-map',
  lat: 40.574859,
  lng: -105.056756,
  width: '100%',
          height: '500px',
          scrollwheel: false,
    });
    map.addMarker({
      lat: 40.574859,
      lng: -105.056756,
      title: 'Fort Collins Office',
              infoWindow: {
                content: '<div class="bubble-wrap"><p class="office">Fort Collins Office</p><p>1120 E. Elizabeth St.</p><p>Suite F-101</p><p>Fort Collins, CO 80524</p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//1120+E+Elizabeth+St,+Fort+Collins,+CO+80524/@40.5748591,-105.0567559,17z/data=!4m13!1m4!3m3!1s0x87694ae0b3695899:0x5510539035305077!2s1120+E+Elizabeth+St!3b1!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x87694ae0b3695899:0x5510539035305077!2m2!1d-105.0567559!2d40.5748591">Directions</a></div>'
              }
    });
});
/**
  * Loveland Map
  */
$(document).ready(function () {
map = new GMaps({
  div: '#loveland-map',
  lat: 40.431917,
  lng: -105.078848,
  width: '100%',
          height: '500px',
          scrollwheel: false,
    });
    map.addMarker({
      lat: 40.431917,
      lng: -105.078848,
      title: 'Loveland Office',
              infoWindow: {
                content: '<div class="bubble-wrap"><p class="office">Loveland Office</p><p>3820 N. Grant Ave.</p><p>Loveland, CO 80538</p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//3820+N+Grant+Ave,+Loveland,+CO+80538/@40.4319173,-105.0788668,17z/data=!4m13!1m4!3m3!1s0x8769528a066dd4ad:0x2b893ca80de0bd33!2s3820+N+Grant+Ave!3b1!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x8769528a066dd4ad:0x2b893ca80de0bd33!2m2!1d-105.0788668!2d40.4319173">Directions</a></div>'
              }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

trigger the resize-event of the window when a tab is **shown**(`shown` fires later than `click`, when the tab is already visible):

```
$('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize', {});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BAm69/

Comment: @AdamRobertson, I've used above sample its not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

http://jsfiddle.net/7PueE/

`<li onclick="loadmap()"><a href="#loveland" id="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Loveland</a></li>`

```
function loadmap() {
    var nmap = new GMaps({
        div: '#loveland-map',
        lat: 40.431917,
        lng: -105.078848,
        width: '100%',
        height: '500px',
        scrollwheel: false,
    });
    nmap.addMarker({
        lat: 40.431917,
        lng: -105.078848,
        title: 'Loveland Office',
        infoWindow: {
            content: '<div class="bubble-wrap"><p class="office">Loveland Office</p><p>3820 N. Grant Ave.</p><p>Loveland, CO 80538</p><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//3820+N+Grant+Ave,+Loveland,+CO+80538/@40.4319173,-105.0788668,17z/data=!4m13!1m4!3m3!1s0x8769528a066dd4ad:0x2b893ca80de0bd33!2s3820+N+Grant+Ave!3b1!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x8769528a066dd4ad:0x2b893ca80de0bd33!2m2!1d-105.0788668!2d40.4319173">Directions</a></div>'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. Still the same weird cropping.