# Refresh Google map in Jquery Multiple Step Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have a Jquery form with multiple step and the second step I want to put a google map div.
At now this GMAP div is not working, just partly showing. I've read many questions about refreshig map in Bootstrap tabs but I don't know how to apply it for my case.

I've tried with this code

**HTML**

```
<fieldset> <!--step 1-->
some inputs
<input type="button" name="next" class="refresh next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset> <!--step 2-->
<div id="maphome"></div> <!-- NOT LOADING THE MAP -->
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

**jQUERY/JS (I've tried)**

```
var addressPicker = new AddressPicker({
    map: {
        id: '#maphome',
        styles: <?php echo $map_style; ?>
    }
});

// instantiate the typeahead UI

$('#address').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'description',
    source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
});

// Bind some event to update map on autocomplete selection

$('#address').bind('typeahead:selected', addressPicker.updateMap);
$('#address').bind('typeahead:cursorchanged', addressPicker.updateMap);

//This is not refreshing

$('.refresh').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }, 50);
});
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google maps can't be initialized on a hidden element. When are you initializing the map?

Comment: Oh well there was a typing error in the question. <div id="map"></div> is actually <div id="maphome"></div> which is called initialized into the AddressPicker function.

Comment: Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the error logs? Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544792/how-to-reload-google-map-in-bootstrap-jquery-tab) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a height class to #maphome if you don't already have one there.

Comment: mmm, It's already at 300px. I actually see the Google Logo but the map is all grey... @ERushforth